# Benchmarked effects of disk defragment in windows

Tags: windows, defragment

Is there a study or something I could have a look at to find out how and to what extend disk defragment improves performance in windows?

A benchmarking study to show the before and after effects would be perfect

Comment: Note: Windows-7 defragments drives every week or so automatically

Comment: My personal records shows this

case: folder structure of 20000 files that has grown organically under WindowsXP/NTFS. To list all file names (yes just list) it takes 21minutes. After defrag under 2 minutes. Of course cache have been cleared between benchmarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firms the sell defragging software, such as [Diskeeper](http://www.diskeeper.com/business/diskeeper/) have published studies, of course they may be biased as they want you to buy defragging software ;-)

Here is their [white paper](http://downloads.diskeeper.com/pdf/Windows_IT_Pro_Reliability.pdf).

Comment: reading two pages of that paper convinced me that diskeeper not just cleans your disks but also cures cancer and aids and makes you rich and famous.